# Excel: Extract data from well beneath unique identifier

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet full of data (simplified example below) that I would like to extract the number in the well underneath of "Gimme the number" and paste it into a new column on a separate sheet (i.e. if "Gimme the number" is in G6, I would like to retrieve the value for G7). I do not have access to Excel VBA and have not used macros in the past. I found some examples linked below, but, from what I understand, they would return "Gimme the number", or "Gimme" not 19, 20, and 21. I am not sure if a pivot table is appropriate, because I only want information from a single column. I will only have up to 11 values to extract at any given time, so I think a formula would do it. I am just having a hard time coming up with one that works. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Data Spreadsheet]

[Search for a text string and return multiple adjacent values](https://www.get-digital-help.com/search-for-a-text-string-and-return-multiple-adjacent-values/)

[Return multiple matches with wildcard vlookup](https://www.get-digital-help.com/return-multiple-matches-with-wildcard-vlookup-in-excel/)

Comment: Your first link ([search for a text string](https://www.get-digital-help.com/search-for-a-text-string-and-return-multiple-adjacent-values/)) has exactly what you want I believe. What part isn't working? Can you show the formula for how you tried to adapt it to your spreadsheet?

Comment: Please read this help article that explains how to ask a question that will get good answers. This will help avoid frustration. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I get the question well, but I try.

First add a column right of the column with "Gimme..." values. Name it e.g. "Next_value" in the first row. Put in the formula referencing previous column next row. If "Gimme..." is in the cell (for instance) E6, than your formula in the cell F6 is `=E7`. Copy that formula into the whole Next_value column.

Than select area of these two columns (Label, Next_value) and apply the filter from the Data toolbar. Use the small buttons with triangles at the top of the column Label to adjust the filter so only "Gimme..." rows are filtered.

Now, copy values of Next_value column where you like. If you want just the references, use Paste special function from the Home toolbar and click Paste link button.